# What organization should be used to represent two types of data that can be associated with any number of the other type?

Tags: mysql, database

This is an issue that I get stumped by when working in MySQL frequently.  I can't remember all of the different cases where something like this has come up, so I am trying to state it abstractly.

Say I have data type A and data type B.  There are multiple instances of A and multiple instances of B.  I want to form links between instances of A and instances of B, so that any instance of A might be associated with no Bs, with all Bs, or with any set of Bs.  I want this relationship to be two way.  So sometimes I think of it in terms of "what set of Bs are related to this instance of A", but other times I think of it in terms of "what set of As are related to this instance of B".  Most importantly there must be a way to search the database and get all of the Bs related to an A, or all of the As related to a B.

If I didn't need it to be two way (say I only needed to get a set of Bs given an A) then I could just have one of the columns in the A table be a string containing all of the B ids separated by commas or something.  But then if I have the id of a B and want to go the other way I would have to look at every A individually and look through the list of ids to find the matches.  That seems like too much work for me and the computer.

It seems to me like I could create a table (maybe called A_and_B) that would consist of two columns.  One column would be ids of A and the other ids of B.  Each entry in this table would represent a link between an instance of A and an instance of B.  Then finding what I am looking for is always a relatively straightforward MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM B_table WHERE id IN (SELECT B_id FROM A_and_B WHERE A_id='X')
```

Here is my major question:  Is this a good idea or a bad idea and why?
I also have a minor questions:  Is there better terminology I could be use to phrase this whole question more concisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very standard way of doing it. It goes by several names: a Link table, an association table. a Many-Many table, and probably more.

You idea in your 3rd paragraph of concatenating id's into one field, however, is terrible. Sadly it is also fairly commonly used by database novices. It can be made to work, but making it work is a) usually harder than it should be and b) leaves an unmaintainable and unexpandable mess. You should use the same technique of an association table (for M-M) or a simple FK on the target table (for 1-M); any relationship may be characterised as 'one way' at a point in time, but sooner or later a requirement comes up that will need traversing the link in the other way and so it wasn't 'one way' after all.

I'd argue that no relationship can be 'one way'. As an analogy, if I know who my friends are is it reasonable to expect one of them not to know about me? That knowledge may not be useful at any or many points in time, but it's there.

Comment: Very helpful.  Could you explain this sentence, this is the only one where you lost me: "You should use the same technique of an association table (for M-M) or a simple FK on the target table (for 1-M);"

Comment: It was a bit confused, yes; sorry. I was talking about the situation you describe in the 3rd paragraph, and how I would solve it: if it was a one-to-one relationship (each B is referenced by 1 or zero A's) then put A's PK in table B as an FK to a. If it's a many-to-many relationship (each A can reference many B's and each B can be referenced by many A's) then a link table is the answer. Does that help?

Comment: Ahh I see.  I still don't know what PK and FK mean, but I see what you mean now.  My main confusion with this problem has been that most of the help online only shows the one-to-one or one-to-many relationships.  And I didn't even know the terminology to search.  This has been very helpful.

Comment: Good! PK is primary key, and indicates that the column that is the PK of the table has a unique value in each row, and hence uniquely identifies the row. FK is Foreign Key. This is a column which has the value of the PK from another table, and indicates which row in that other table this tow is related to. For example, a Customer table might have a PK column called CustomerId; a related CustomerTransaction table whould also have a column called CustomerId, containing the CustomerId from the Customer row of the customer involved. Cheers -